# change HTTP headers for all requests in Alamofire

Tags: swift, http-headers, alamofire, nsurlrequest

I am using Alamofire for network calls.

The main function is as:

```
public func request(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> Request {

...

    return request
}
```

So I created my URLRequestConvertible and ran Alamofire's *request* method. WHILE I also attempt to add HTTP-headers.

```
public func request(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> Request {

URLRequest.setValue("\random()" , forHTTPHeaderField : "identifier"
URLRequest.setValue("\buildversion()" , forHTTPHeaderField : "build"

    return request
}
```

But nothing happens, no headers are added! Only headers that were added *before* the request method call exist.

The problem is I believe URLRequest is `get` only and I can't `set` it.  Is there any workaround?

```
public protocol URLRequestConvertible {
    /// The URL request.
    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest { get }
}
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

`URLRequest` is a struct so you modify the method-local copy; the change never propagates outside.

You solve this by making the parameter `inout`:

```
public func request(request: inout URLRequestConvertible) -> Request {
    ...
}
```

Call-site, you will have to explicitly mark the parameter as well:

```
let myRequest = ...
request(&myRequest)
```

Notes:

- If accessibility would have been the issue, you'd have received a compiler error.
- The official coding style guidelines tell us to use lower-case letters for variables.
- Using types as variable names is not very informative; having a method of the same name even less so.